# A different way to convert an atom to number

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am getting some input from a file. In the begining i read it as atoms, and then convert it to number. In my case it is important to keep the "number" exactly the same. For example, if the input is 0456 the atom will be 0456 but when converted to number it will be 456. It is important to keep the number exactly the same -even the 0 in the beggining. I need to have it in number form cause i have to make divisions etc. For that reason i think that keeping as an atom is not possible thus, i am looking for a method to keep the number as is.

An example input is like:
1234
4563
0789
4560

The "reading" code is the following:

```c
read_a_line(Stream, Number) :-
    read_line_to_codes(Stream,Line),
    atom_codes(Atom,Line),
    atom_number(Atom,Number).
```

Comment: Internally, numbers are represented in binary, not as a sequence of characters. There simply isn't anywhere for a leading zero to be kept in the numeric representation. So I don't think your requirement is achievable. You have to keep it around as an atom and just convert it to a number when you need to do arithmetic with it.

Comment: You could also convert them immediately to numbers and then, when you want to view them, reformat them for display using leading 0's where needed. The leading 0's (even the base of 10) is merely for visual representation of a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a complex term to represent your special kind of numbers in your program. In a functional language you'd consider this a custom data type. So let's make a type of number that can have a prefix. It'll be of the form:

```
no(1234). % 1234 
no(0, 123). % 0123
```

You'll need some methods to convert back and forth between atoms:

```
atom_no(X, no(N)) :-
    atom_number(X, N),
    atom_number(Y, N),
    X == Y, !.
atom_no(X, no(P, N)) :-
    atom(X),
    atom_number(X, N),
    atom_concat(P, N, X), !.
atom_no(X, no(P, N)) :-
    integer(N),
    atom_number(Y, N),
    atom_concat(P, Y, X).
```

Note these can be queried forwards and backwards:

```
?- atom_no('1234', N).
N = no(1234).

?- atom_no(A, no(1234)).
A = '1234'.

?- atom_no('0123', N).
N = no(0, 123).

?- atom_no(A, no(0, 123)).
A = '0123'.
```

Then you'll need conversion predicates to convert your number type into something you can do mathematics with:

```
int_no(I, no(I)).
int_no(I, no(_, I)).
```

Then an integer division with these numbers would be something like:

```
div(A, B, no(O)) :-
    int_no(AI, A),
    int_no(BI, B),
    O is A // B.
```

If your numbers are a set length and you want calculated numbers to be output with leading zeros, you'll want to adapt the `atom_no/2` predicate to suit your domain better.